# Catching DoesNotExist exception in a custom manager in Django

Tags: python, django, exception, django-custom-manager

I have a custom manager for a Django model. I don't seem to be able to catch DoesNotExist exception here. I know how to do it inside the model but it didn't work here:

```
class TaskManager(models.Manager):
    def task_depend_tree(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if "id" in kwargs:
            try:
                task = self.get(id=kwargs["id"])
            except DoesNotExist:
                raise Http404
```

Get_object_or_404 doesn't work either.
What is wrong here?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean, for both those cases? What actually happens?

Comment: @DanielRoseman  NameError: global name 'DoesNotExist' is not defined

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Try either using `ObjectDoesNotExist` instead of `DoesNotExist` or possibly `self.DoesNotExist`. If all else fails, just try and catch a vanilla `Exception` and evaluate it to see it's type().

`from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist`

Comment: I had tried Self.DoesNotExist and it failed. The error I get when something doesn't exist in database is: `NameError: global name 'DoesNotExist' is not defined` So I need to import DoesNotExist from somewhere. I assumed it is in models.Model but models.Model.DoesNotExist didn't work.

Comment: self.DoesNotExist will obviously not help, because self exists if it has such a method. Use instead `task.DoesNotExist` or `ObjectDoesNotExist`.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion of `ObjectDoesNotExist`? The other syntax might be self.model.DoesNotExist... but I'm not sure off the top of my head.

Comment: I had to import ObjectDoesNotExist and it worked to catch DoesNotExist: `from django.db.models.base import ObjectDoesNotExist
`  Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

As panchicore suggested, `self.model` is the way to go.

```
class TaskManager(models.Manager):
    def task_depend_tree(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if "id" in kwargs:
            try:
                task = self.get(id=kwargs["id"])
            except self.model.DoesNotExist:
                raise Http404
```

Answer (score 6):

If you need to implement this on a list method (DRF) using GenericViewSet, and need an empty list to be returned, use this:

```
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.get_object() # I use this to trigger the object_permission
    try:
        queryset = self.queryset.filter(user=(YourModel.objects.get(user=request.user).user))
    except YourModel.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(YourModel.objects.none())

    serializer = YSourModelSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: This is the cleanest way of handling this exception since it does not involve importing the Exception

Answer (score 2):

you can use the DoesNotExist from the Manager.model (self.model) instance,
when you say `objects = MyManager()` you are assigning self.model inside MyManager class.

```
        try:
            task = self.get(id=kwargs["id"])
            return task
        except self.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Comment: This will not work. You have to use self.model.DoesNotExist

Answer (score 1):

In Django, every object from model has an exception property `DoesNotExists`. So you can call it from the object itself or from the exceptions module.

From object (`self`):

```
from django.db import models

class TaskManager(models.Manager):
    def task_depend_tree(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if "id" in kwargs:
            try:
                task = self.get(id=kwargs["id"])
            except self.model.DoesNotExist:
                raise Http404
```

From exceptions module:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

try:
    return "Calling object"
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    raise Http404
```

Answer (score 0):

I handle the exception this way and it worked.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

try:
    task = self.get(id=kwargs["id"])
except ObjectDoesNotExist as DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404
```

Comment: The name DoesNotExist is quite misleading here and not used at all